Command to know the speed between mainboard and HDD/SSD
I want to know the speed of data transfer between a HDD or SSD and the
mainboard. It through a command. If is possible through a GUI, it is accepted too
Goal:
I want to do a comparison of speeds against

Thunderbolt 3/4/5 if is connected through a docking station with a M.2 NvME PCIe

versus

SSD (HDD) and the mainboard

Thus I want to know how viable would be install Linux in a secondary SSD through a docking station with Thunderbolt. How similar would be the time of response of Linux running with that approach?
I know thunderbolt has the following values about speed

Thunderbolt 1: 10 Gbit/s per channel, or 20 Gbit/s total
Thunderbolt 2: 20 Gbit/s total
Thunderbolt 3 and 4: 40 Gbit/s bidirectional
Thunderbolt 5: 80 Gbit/s bidirectional

So, If the difference is really huge against the mobo/SSD thus I must consider use dual boot but it takes space in the primary disk.

Is the SSD (HDD) and the mainboard connected via SATA, or is it NVMe?

Note that the speeds you've listed are bus speeds, and actual read and write speed of the disk are likely lower.

@ChesterGillon good point - it is for both scenarios. "user10489" Thanks for that point too


I want to know the speed of data transfer between a HDD or SSD and the mainboard

Then look up your interface link standard on wikipedia.

Thus I want to know how viable would be install Linux in a secondary SSD through a docking station with Thunderbolt. How similar would be the time of response of Linux running with that approach?

All the thunderbolt standards you mention are way faster than SSDs sold in M.2 form factors can sustain, so the revision of that link standard is of no consequence to your use case.
HDDs? Orders of magnitude slower, typically.
Therefore:
The sensible benchmark would hence actually be testing read, write and access time speeds with the storage medium; the link speed is of minor to no concern. You would pick the parameters of such a benchmark as close as possible to the real-world use case of running an OS from that external medium.
In all honesty, installing a modern Linux on an SSD takes 15 minutes. Using that Linux for 10 minutes will give you definite information on its speed. That's the optimal benchmark; of all possible benchmarks, it's the one with the most information on how well something works for the intended use case; hence all other possible benchmarks are inferior in representativity. Because it is actually the intended use case.
So, why are we even talking about that? Go ahead and try. Download just about any modern Linux distro's installer image (debian, Ubuntu, Fedora), put that image onto a separate USB thumb drive (e.g. using the Fedora Media Writer, which can either use an already downloaded image or download one itself), boot from that USB thumb drive, and install the Linux distro onto your thunderbolt drive.

The big question here, boils down to:
How to measure the "practical speed" of a storage device.
The answer is there are very many ways, and the practical end result will most likely be: none of them will tell you a single truth, but MANY truths.
All depends on HOW you measure, and how well that does match with a real world situation.

Large files will most likely be possible to READ fast, e.g. into a RAM-buffer, if read in large chunks.
Numerous SMALL files will impose a large amount of ADMINISTRATIVE tasks, which will impose a (huge) time penalty.
Reading RANDOM spread out blocks of data from a HDD will be impacted by SEEK timing (moving the read head)
... and so on

One way to do read testing, SSD and NVME media:
$ lsblk -ape7
NAME             MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
/dev/sda           8:0    0  7,3T  0 disk 
...
/dev/nvme0n1     259:0    0  3,6T  0 disk 
...

$ sudo dd if=/dev/nvme0n1 of=/dev/null bs=4k count=10M status=progress
42357981184 bytes (42 GB, 39 GiB) copied, 53 s, 799 MB/s 
10485760+0 records in
10485760+0 records out
42949672960 bytes (43 GB, 40 GiB) copied, 53,7492 s, 799 MB/s
    
$ sudo dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/dev/null bs=4k count=10M status=progress
42673651712 bytes (43 GB, 40 GiB) copied, 84 s, 508 MB/s 
10485760+0 records in
10485760+0 records out
42949672960 bytes (43 GB, 40 GiB) copied, 84,5294 s, 508 MB/s

dmidecode:
 system-manufacturer: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
 system-product-name: ROG Strix G731GU_G731GU

... but then: How well does this reflect practical use?
This is reading a good amount of data from sequential block from the devices, so might give an idea - but practical use is hardly reading more than a few KB at a time (buffering involved), unless it is e.g. a large file e.g. ISO image, Video or some such.
As soon as there is a file system involved, it will impose an administrative penalty. How heavy that is depends on the file system.
(The details of a file system;
AmigaDOS  OFS and FFS are easy to understand, covered in detail by "The AmigaDOS Manual")

nice! But as I said in my answer, the optimal benchmark is the one that gives you the most information on how well something will perform under your specific use case; so, in this case the best possible benchmark is literally just installing to and booting off the external device

I'm not fully convinced by your dd benchmark, and I can tell you why: it's small chunked in user land / kernel interface (i.e., reads happen in sizes of 4 kB), but fully sequential. Most use cases where reads are small chunked are random, and most use cases that are sequential for 42 GB are larger-chunked; this is a stress test for some aspects of the storage device and storage subsystem that aren't really that representative for how things would behave under real-world usage. Here's the thing: reasonable people could argue for hours how to design a benchmark that is as similar as a…

… user working "regularly" from that storage device. But, if we just let the user use the device, they will come back with the actual only benchmark that matters: is it fast enough? Anything else is moot. "OK, but a video editing workflow could be 10% faster" is irrelevant even to professional video editors if the current 91% are good enough, for example. It would be doubly irrelevant if the user edits less than 5 videos a year and would wait an extra second.

The actual test here isn't meant to be more than an indication of what one might see; I have added quite a bit of text pointing out the problems that are apparent, and also indicated that there is quite a bit of more problems in this, that can be seen as fully in line with your comments, if read with the mindset I intended.

honestly, your question starts out with some strong state assumption on access patterns based on usage type; and that's really the thing you need to address: these assumptions are, in my opinion, wrong (small files on a file system that is designed for this might not be bad, and it's not clear what you mean with "ADMINISTRATIVE tasks", because that is irrelevant to the performance of storag access (most file system metadata will be cached after the first file has been read), and so are the tests you describe; they all are based on the same fundamental mistake: that a benchmark that's not based

My question? Sorry, this was never intended to cover anything more than the basics. The actual implementation, buffering and such is clearly left out beyond simple mentions. I'd say the text is correct on a general level, and was never intended to be more than so.

… in a metric that actually counts is meaningful. You can measure a lot of things – and very few will help asses how well something works; this isn't special about storage at all. Imagine telling someone how well a car works by first getting it to 240 km/h as possible (for high speed sequential loads), and then testing it by accelerating how fast you can for 50 m, then taking a 90° turn, then accelerating for 50m, then 90°… (for small-inner city errand loads). These two certainly give you interesting data about the driver-car system, but are going to be not going to help any real driver.

Have good day, stay calm and be nice to people.

I'm calm :) I hoped that explaining why I didn't upvote your answer (something I usually do on questions where I have an answer of my own and someone else writes a high-effort answer!) was interesting to you; sorry if you felt annoyed by that. But I do wish really wish you have a good day :)
